# Autolayout view doesn't react to rotation of the phone

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, autolayout, xcode5

Perhaps I'm missing something obvious but for some reason my Autolayout view doesn't react to rotation of the phone. It works in different sample project I created but I don't seem to be able how and where it's enabled.

Could you please suggest what it can be ? I posted problematic XIB here: http://pastebin.com/Sb6ch6Ln

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, it's set in app's plist in parameter `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations`. Sorry for false alarm guys!